# Lambda order by parameter performance

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-6

I have a performance problem I can't solve. If you look at the code below it works fine, but when I change the `OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)` so it uses the paramater `sortOrder` instead, it gives me a timeout.

Im calling the function with the same lambda expression that I supplied in the `OrderByDescending`.

```
m_DAL.GetPastes(page, userName, x => x.ID).ToList<Paste>();
```

This works but i want to be able to pass the sortOrder as a parameter.

```
    public IEnumerable<Paste> GetPastes(int page, string username, Func<Paste, object> sortOrder)
    {
        return this.Filter<Paste>(x => x.Expires == null || x.Expires > DateTime.UtcNow)
            .Where(x => x.AccessMode.Key == 1 || (x.AccessMode.Key == 2 && x.User.UserName == username))
            .Where(x => x.CaptchaOK == true || (x.AccessMode.Key == 2 && x.User.UserName == username))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.ID)
            .Skip(m_pagesize * page)
            .Take(m_pagesize)
            .ToList<Paste>();
    }
```

This is giving me a timeout:

```
public IEnumerable<Paste> GetPastes(int page, string username, Func<Paste, object> sortOrder)
    {
        return this.Filter<Paste>(x => x.Expires == null || x.Expires > DateTime.UtcNow)
            .Where(x => x.AccessMode.Key == 1 || (x.AccessMode.Key == 2 && x.User.UserName == username))
            .Where(x => x.CaptchaOK == true || (x.AccessMode.Key == 2 && x.User.UserName == username))
            .OrderByDescending(sortOrder)
            .Skip(m_pagesize * page)
            .Take(m_pagesize)
            .ToList<Paste>();
    }
```

How can I resolve this problem? Is it the definition of the function that is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use just `Func<Paste, object>` - you get overload of `OrderBy` that retrieves all entites to memory and orders them. For getting more performance I would recommend you using `Expression<T>` which would be translated in SQL and run on db side:

EDIT:
Also you could make your method generic for omiting this:

> NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type
>   'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive
>   or enumeration types.

```
public IEnumerable<Paste> GetPastes<TOrderKey>(int page, string username, 
                   Expression<Func<Paste, TOrderKey>> sortOrder)
{
    // code from the question
}
```

Note that the way you call this method won't change because of type inference:

```
m_DAL.GetPastes(page, userName, x => x.ID).ToList<Paste>();
```

Comment: Exactly, while you can convert from an expression<func> to a func the reverse isn't true, linq to iqueryables (any database provider) works on expressions to generate sql, if you pass a func you're going down to link to objects, this means you're retrieving ALL the rows from the db, then getting each one of them into the orderby. So if your page size is 20 and your table contains 2million rows, 1st example retrieves 20rows from the db to your application, second one retrieves 2 millions, is perfectly normal that it's substantially slower.

Comment: That almost worked. =) It solved the performance issue but i had to change object to int or i get an error "Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Comment: Can you update your example with a generic version? object didnt seem to work for me.